# Getting network error while trying to pass form data from localhost:5173 to localhost:3000/register with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, axios

I keep getting network error (POST http://localhost/3000/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) whenever I submit a form from localhost:5173/register using axios in chrome browser while in firefox I get (Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/3000/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null));

This is my frontend code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const registerUrl = "http://localhost/3000/register";

const Register = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    secondName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    state: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post(registerUrl, input);
      console.log(input);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    setInput({
      firstName: "",
      secondName: "",
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-full sm:w-3/4 md:w-2/4 p-3 my-10 mx-auto bg-teal-300 shadow-sm shadow-gray-400">
        <div className="w-3/4 mx-auto">
          <h2 className="uppercase text-teal-800 text-xl pt-5">
            Register User
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-3/4 mx-auto p-3 text-teal-800">
            <label htmlFor="">First Name</label>
            <input
              className="p-2 rounded-md bg-teal-100 outline-none focus:bg-teal-50"
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={input.firstName}
              placeholder="First Name"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setInput({ ...input, firstName: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-3/4 mx-auto p-3 text-teal-800">
            <label htmlFor="">Second Name</label>
            <input
              className="p-2 rounded-md bg-teal-100 outline-none focus:bg-teal-50"
              type="text"
              name="secondName"
              value={input.secondName}
              placeholder="Second Name"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setInput({ ...input, secondName: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center mb-8">
            <button
              type="submit"
              value="submit"
              className="bg-teal-600 w-3/4 mx-auto shadow-sm shadow-gray-300 hover:bg-teal-400 text-white p-4 border-none outline-none"
            >
              Sumbit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

and this is my backend code

```
import express from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import cors from "cors";


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const newUser = [];
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.send(newUser);
});

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const user = {
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      secondName: req.body.secondName,
      password: hashedPassword,
      email: req.body.email,
      dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
      phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
      state: req.body.state,
    };
    newUser.push(user);
    res.sendStatus(201);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Sending the data via request.rest on vcode works fine. But sending the data from across the localhost fails.